# Numbers appearing in scientific notation after imputing missing values with mean in a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, missing-data

I have imputed missing values with mean for my dataset but post this process I can see that the amount values are showing in a scientific format, though the data type is still float64. I have used the following code :

```
mean_value1=df1['amount'].mean()
df1['amount']=df1['amount'].fillna(mean_value1)
df1['start_balance']=df1['start_balance'].fillna(mean_value2)
mean_value3=df1['end_balance'].mean()
df1['end_balance']=df1['end_balance'].fillna(mean_value3)
df1 = df1.fillna(df1.mode().iloc[0])
df1.head()
```

missing values are treated correctly but the values for start balance and end balance are coming in scientific notation. How can I prevent this to happen? 
The output looks like following:

```
 amount         booking_date    booking_text    date_end_balance    date_start_balance  end_balance month    start_balance  tx_code
-60790.332082   2017-06-30  SEPA-Gutschrift    2017-06-30           2017-06-01          2.693179e+07     June-2017  2.652441e+07    166.0
-10.000000      2016-03-22  GEBUEHREN          2016-03-22           2016-02-22          3.589838e+06    March-2016  3.590838e+06    808.0
```

Comment: do you have to keep all the decimal places in the number?

Comment: nope. I just need one whole number

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to round the numbers you can change how they are displayed in the output this way

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(5)*10000000000, columns=['random'])
pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.0f' % x)

df
```

which gives this output

```
        random
0  7591769472
1 78148991059
2 19880680453
3  1965830619
4 39390983843
```

instead of this output

```
         random
0  6.704323e+10
1  6.714734e+10
2  8.447027e+09
3  3.051957e+10
4  1.481439e+09
```

change `%.0f` to whatever number of decimal places you want to see from the numbers so two change 0 to 2, 3 0 to 3 etc.

you can also use `df.apply(lambda x: '%.0f' % x, axis=1)` as well

Comment: I am looking for a solution where I can pass a fomatter within my code.

Comment: @Django0602 what do you mean? it doesn't store the values in scientific notation only displays them that way

Answer (score 0):

```
 df1['amount'] = df1['amount'].astype('int64')
 df1['start_balance'] = df1['start_balance'].astype('int64')
```

This worked for me well! in a different step but still worked